# Could not create constraint or index or foreign key on primary key of existing table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I created a table `Demo`. I want its key `Customer_ID_f` to reference to primary key `CustomerID` of some other table named `Customers`.

**DEMO Table(with foreign key)**

```
CREATE TABLE Demo (
ID int NOT NULL,
LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
Age int Not Null,
City varchar(200) DEFAULT 'Sydney',
OrderDate DATE DEFAULT getdate(),
CHECK (AGe>=18),
Customer_ID_f char(5) not null
PRIMARY KEY (ID),
FOREIGN KEY (Customer_ID_f) REFERENCES Customers(CustomerID))
```

**Customers table with primary key**

Information about the character `CustomerID` of `Customers` table.

```
Select *
From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
Where TABLE_NAME = 'Customers';
```

```
    TABLE_SCHEMA    TABLE_NAME  COLUMN_NAME ORDINAL_POSITION    COLUMN_DEFAULT  IS_NULLABLE   DATA_TYPE CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH    CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH      
    dbo             Customers  CustomerID            1         NULL             NO              nchar                     5                 10
```

As you can see that in `Customers` table, the primary key has nchar of length 5 (max_length), i use the same with my demo table. Still I am getting error.

**Error**:

> Column 'Customers.CustomerID' is not the same data type as referencing column 'Demo.Customer_ID_f' in foreign key
> 'FK__Demo__Customer_I__690797E6'.
>
> Msg 1750, Level 16, State 1, Line 156
> Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

Comment: you should create table within FK - then insert data in `Demo.Customer_ID_f` like `Customers.CustomerID` then create FK between two table

Comment: im accessing northwind database customers... table `Customers` is already created. cant recreate it

Comment: Customer_ID_f is primary in your Demo table, not use this column for primary

Comment: No `ID` field is primary, `Customer_ID_f` is not primary in `Demo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one :

```
CREATE TABLE Demo (
ID int NOT NULL  PRIMARY KEY identity(1,1),
LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
Age int Not Null,
City varchar(200) DEFAULT 'Sydney',
OrderDate DATE DEFAULT getdate(),
CHECK (AGe>=18),
Customer_ID_f nchar(5)
)

ALTER TABLE Demo 
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Demo_Customer_ID 
FOREIGN KEY (Customer_ID_f) REFERENCES Customers(CustomerID)
```

Comment: `Column 'Customers.CustomerID' is not the same data type as referencing column 'Demo.Customer_ID_f' in foreign key 'FK_Demo_Customer_ID'.
`
Getting same error...I am using Northwind dataset Customers. You can try the same thing on your laptop too....It is not working

Comment: can you send customer create table script?

Comment: @ShailajaGuptaKapoor why use char(5) try this by `Customer_ID_f nchar(5)`

Comment: `Drop table IF Exists DEMO`... and use my answer... i edited